# Forcing a C# 64bit application to run as 32bit?

Tags: c#, 64-bit

Let's say that when i've compiled a managed assembly, i've forced it to be 64 bit (using the configuration manager). and let's say, that after the compilation i want to run that application as a 32bit process. can i force it to be 32bit again?
i tried to play around and edit the PEHeader (the Machine and 32BitOnly fields), but the application won't start on a 32bit platform.
is there a difference in the produced IL when i force the compile it as 64bit? (in comparison to AnyCPU)

Comment: This begs the question - why? Just curious. What are the gains over Any CPU?

Comment: @Preet: Interaction with 32-bit COM components

Comment: By "Won't start" I assume you're seeing an error, what error?

Comment: @Binary Worrier, "... is not a valid win32 application"

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using one of the many approaches discussed here: http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a difference in the IL, the difference in the the non-managed headers.  64 bit mode compiles an EXE with a [PE32+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format header (that is 64 bit).  So just changing a flag won't change the actual format of the EXE.  That's the reason you get the error that it is not a valid 32bit applications, it's not, it's a 64 bit application and 32 bit Window's can't parse the PE32+ header.

You would have to completely rewrite the EXE to PE32 format, so it probably isn't possible.

Can't you just recompile or is this just for your own interest?

Comment: own interest.. why would the compiler use a PE32+ format? why not to use the regular format and just add the appropriate flags in the .Net section of the header? (like it does with AnyCPU/32bit). What kind of benefits are there?

Comment: I have no idea.  My guess is that it was a cheap way to make sure the code only ran on 64 bit systems - by making a file that only 64 bit OS would read, they didn't have to code anything in the run time to handle that case.

Comment: At some point you have to have native code in the assembly for the OS to read and understand what to do with the file.  Best way to describe is "at some point the rubber must touch the road".  There is no such think as a generic PE (portable executable) format because the two OS speak different languages in terms of memory management and types.